# Regex for a number in the range 1900 and 2020

Tags: regex

How to build a regex for a number in the range 1900 and 2020 inclusive?

Comment: assuming integers: `^(?!(19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)$)(-[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]*)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NO such number that is less than 1900 and greater than 2020. Assuming instead you meant a number in the range 1900 <= x <= 2020, you can use the following regex:

```
^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OA3ss8/1)

Answer (score -1):

This website can help you:
http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

```
(19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)
```

Comment: I see you are assuming OR as mentioned in the comment on the question. But are you sure `199[0-9]` should be there? Wouldn't that match numbers 1990 to 1999 which is not expected by the OP? I also see you used that regex generator you linked, but wrongly modified the result to for the question at hand 

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ You're interpreting the answer's assumption incorrectly. This answer is meant to interpret the question as "a number greater than or equal to 1900, and less than or equal to 2020".

Comment: Oh yes, I realized that just a minute ago. In that case it is correct, but could be shortened, I think. `(19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|2020)`